# Crystal Report Group by Field

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports, report

I am attempting to group by order #, and display this as one row.However since the same order #, the 'Total' should only add 47.66 once.

I've attempted to use the group expert to no avail. I can do this in SQL but can't design it Crystal reports.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new group by Order # and move all items from the detail section to the header of the Order # group. This should do the trick of displaying it as a single row.